# Meaning Of Spring Cron Expression “* */1 * * * ?”

Tags: java, spring, cron

i am new to Spring and cron and in my code this expression is used: “* */1 * * * ?”. I cannot figured out what this means. I have searched already on google and tried this expression on a few sites:

https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html#crongenerator

and

https://crontab.guru/

It told me that this means "Close
Every minute starting at :00 minute after the hour" and the second site told me "At every minute past every hour.” but correlating with the logs from the Bug, i cannot understand when in fact this is triggered.

Here are a few excerpts from the logs:

```
         00:24:06.644 [scheduler-5]  - Start of the scanning for operation X

           00:24:31.397 [scheduler-5]    - Start of the scanning for operation Y

            00:31:02.535 [scheduler-5]    - Start of the scanning for operation Z

            00:34:08.458 [scheduler-5]    - Start of the scanning for operation T

            00:36:11.542 [scheduler-5]    - Start of the scanning for operation  A

              00:38:56.887 [scheduler-5]    - Start of the scanning for operation C

             00:47:30.640 [scheduler-2]    - Start of the scanning for operation I

           00:50:19.578 [scheduler-5]    - Start of the scanning for operation B

           00:53:39.860 [scheduler-5]    - Start of the scanning for operation J

           00:56:24.648 [scheduler-5]    - Start of the scanning for operation P

              00:59:06.028 [scheduler-5]    - Start of the scanning for operation F

            01:02:16.596 [scheduler-5]    - Start of the scanning for operation R

             01:05:59.004 [scheduler-5]    - Start of the scanning for operation N

             01:14:06.190 [scheduler-5]    - Start of the scanning for operation O

           01:16:59.551 [scheduler-5]    - Start of the scanning for operation G

             01:19:16.718 [scheduler-5]    - Start of the scanning for operation E

             01:22:01.298 [scheduler-5]    - Start of the scanning for operation H

             01:24:26.732 [scheduler-2]    - Start of the scanning for operation D

             01:25:03.324 [scheduler-5]    - Start of the scanning for operation S

            01:26:29.480 [scheduler-5]    - Start of the scanning for operation K

              01:27:10.503 [scheduler-2]    - Start of the scanning for operation L

             01:28:46.531 [scheduler-5]    - Start of the scanning for operation M
```

How this can run "Close
Every minute starting at :00 minute after the hour" or "At every minute past every hour.” i cannot understand. Could you please help me to understand this?

Comment: Did you have a look [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/CronExpression.html)?

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between `Spring cron expression` and `Unix cron expression`

Spring cron:

```
second, minute, hour, day (of month), month, day (of week)
```

Unix-Cron:

```
minute, hour, day (of month), month, day (of week)
```

If you are looking for a Spring-expression for top of the hour every day, try this:

```
"0 0 * * * *"
```

Comment: I know that there is a difference, but this is already code written by someone else and I am trying to understand what this means, I am not looking for modifying it.